# How to move selected lines up and down?

Tags: selection, movement

Is it possible to move selected lines up and down?

```
c = 3
a = 1
b = 2
```

I would like to select second and third lines and move them one line up, so that result be:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
```

I know that `>` and `<` moves lines right and left, but how to move them up and down?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the [`:move`](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3Amove) ex command:

```
:2,3m0
```

In the above, `2,3` is a [range](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Arange) which specifies which lines we want to move, `m` is an abbreviated form of the `:move` command, and `0` is an [address](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%7Baddress%7D) which specifies where we want the lines to move to.

Comment: Is it possible to move relatively? Because I use `rnu` instead of `nu` and know only relative line numbers.

Comment: @niekas It's possible to `:move` relative to the _cursor_, but not relative to the thing you're moving. e.g. `:2,3m-8` will move lines 2 and 3 to be below the line that is 8 lines before the cursor; it _won't_ move the lines 8 lines upwards (unless your cursor happens to be in the position where that's the same thing).

Comment: Thats just great, I have tried `:2,3m+8` and `:2,3m-8` and they both work relatively. If I don't add a sign before the number, e.g. `:2,3m8` it works with absolute line numbers. Would be nice to see this clarification in the answer :)

Answer (score 4):

You can select the lines with entering visual line mode `V`, deleting with `d` and pasting with `p` (after the cursor) or `P` (before the cursor). But if you need this often I highly recommend to read/watch [Vimcasts episode #26 "Bubbling Text"](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/bubbling-text/), which introduces two generic solutions with keybindings:

```
" Bubble single lines
nmap <C-Up> ddkP
nmap <C-Down> ddp
" Bubble multiple lines
vmap <C-Up> xkP`[V`]
vmap <C-Down> xp`[V`]
```

The second binding needs the excellent plugin [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) by Tim Pope:

```
" Bubble single lines
nmap <C-Up> [e
nmap <C-Down> ]e
" Bubble multiple lines
vmap <C-Up> [egv
vmap <C-Down> ]egv
```